# Linking libraries from JBoss 7 AS modules directory

Tags: java, ant, jboss7.x

If there is a library present in JBoss AS 7 under the `/modules` directory, what is the best way to go about referencing it in my project?

I'm working on a project that used to just throw each module's dependencies in a `/lib` folder, parallel to `/src`.  The Ant build would simply reference those `/lib` folders.

I'm not above simply throwing JBoss in source control, though I don't look forward to referencing each library by their `/modules` sub-directory.  Is there a better way?

If it provides additional avenues of solving the problem: I'm using IntelliJ IDEA, though using an Ant build rather than the default Make build, and we need our Ant build to work from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

JBoss AS7 has a concept of implicit modules dependency.
dependencies for modules like JPA,CDI will get added automaticaly.
You can check the complete list here :
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Implicit+module+dependencies+for+deployments

Otherwise,you would need to add a Dependencies: manifest entry.

This entry consists of a comma separated list of module names that the deployment requires. The available modules can be seen under the modules directory in the application server distribution.

For example to add a dependency on javassist and apache velocity you can add a manifest entry as follows:

Dependencies: org.javassist export,org.apache.velocity export services,org.antlr

You can read more here :
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Developer+Guide#DeveloperGuide-DeploymentModuleNames

Comment: I apologize for my probably silly question, but I don't know java very well yet.  I got the impression that this manifest file was related to which jars get loaded by the AS at deploy/runtime.  I am using Ant for my build, and I need to reference these jar files when compiling.  Is the manifest solution also applicable to this scenario?

Comment: works with Maven, for ANT you would put them in WEB-INF/Lib folder

Comment: Which would defeat the purpose of me linking them in-place.  So you're basically telling me the new JBoss server is built around Maven, and doesn't directly support other build systems very well - is this correct?  BTW, not your fault, you're just the messenger ;)  I think I found a solution to this of using wildcards to specify where the `.jar` files are, relative to the `modules` directory (`**/*.jar`).  Any idea if this would work? (I will of course try it myself)

Comment: um, there is nothing maven-specific here. Just add the manifest header, either with Ant or editing the file yourself. You don't need maven to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use a dependency manager (Maven, Ivy, …) you can either check them in or reference them in the JBoss installation folder. Should you decide to do this you'll probably want to have a variable pointing to the JBoss installation. You need to be able to differentiate between dependencies coming from JBoss and others. The later ones you need to package with our application, the former ones must not go into your application but need to be referenced in [jboss-deployment-structure.xml](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7) (unless [automatically provided by JBoss](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Implicit+module+dependencies+for+deployments)).

Personally I recommend using a dependency manager, they support dependencies that you only need for compilation and will be provided at runtime. And they also provide features for things like JUnit only being needed by the tests and not the application.